# How to prevent keyboard hide after TextBox lost its focus?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a chat application for Windows Phone 8.1 in C# as Windows Runtime application. I wan't to mimic the behaviour found in applications like Skype or Facebook Messenger for Windows Phone, where after you typed your message and tapped on the send button on the AppBar, the keyboard stays in place and you can continue typing your next message.

**What I did so far:**

I tried to set focus back to the TextBox in the event handler of the send button, like this:

```
private async void AppBarButtonSendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = FindChildControl<TextBox>(ChatSection, "TextBoxMessage") as TextBox;
    tb.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);

    if (await HttpHelper.SendMessage(tb.Text))
    {
        RefreshMessages();                
        tb.Text = "";
    }
}
```

(The TextBox is in a Hub control, that is why I'm using the `FindChildControl` method.)

This way the keyboard disappears for a second then reappears, which is annoying. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: The awnser for my question showed up in the Related section. I search for the right solution for a long time but didn't managed to found anything useful, then I post this question and I found it. 
So the soultion is: Set the `AppBarButtonMessage` buttons `IsTabStop` property to `false`.